# Android - Kotlin warning of time libraires

Tags: android, kotlin, time, warnings

I am developing an app which include a method to get time in other time zone.
I managed to do what I want but I have a lot of warning :

[image]

I guess it is due to a API version but it is not clear to me what exactly should I do with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two red bulbs tell you how you can solve this:

**The first bulb:** will add the Oreo suggested annotation on top of your method that is holding your shared code, so that any call of this method should be within the frame of using Oreo version.

**The second bulb:** will surround the part of your code that requires Oreo version with the suggested condition in order to run this code only on devices that are Oreo and above.

**Another suggestion:** make your minimum sdk level to Oreo (API 26), and these warnings will disappear, but you won't be able to run your app on devices that are lower than Oreo

**The last option:** look for another code that replaces your code, if you need to run your app on APIs lower than Oreo.

Comment: Ok i did not understand that O was Oreo (API26), what is usually the best way to deal with this kind of API level issue cause I am afraid that OREO is too recent to be used as the minimal API ?

Comment: yeah O is a bit recent API, as we are now in R, so you need to look for another code for APIs lower than O